# How can I receive string response from laravel with retrofit in android?

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit

I want to post data to Laravel and receive string response from server but i got

> 500 Internal Server Error

Whats wrong with my code?

Retrofit is:

```
 @POST("/saveInfo")
Call<String> sendInfo(
        @Query("name") String name,
        @Query("family") String family,
        @Query("age") String age
```

in fragment:

```
 public void saveInfo(String name,String    family,String age){
    Call<String> call = planApi.sendInfo(name,family,age);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, retrofit2.Response<String> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    if(response.body()=="success")
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "saved successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "saved failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG," Response Error:"+String.valueOf(response.code())+response.message());
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG," Response Error :"+t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "conection failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Router is:

```
Route::post('/saveInfo','BoController@saveInfo');
```

and function  is:

```
public function saveInfo(Request $request)
{
    $student = new Student();
    $student->name = $request->name;
    $student->family = $request->family;
    $student->age= $request->age;
    if($student->save())
       echo "success";
    else
       echo "failed!";
}
```

problem solved!

Should comment the line "`\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`" in **kernel.php** file,use "`@FormUrlEncoded`" and `@Field` for retrofit also in php function type "`echo(json_encode("success/failed"))`"

Comment: add proper error

Comment: @JigneshJoisar E/Volley:  500Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use @Query with POST method. You should use @Field method before each parameter and above @POST, add @FormUrlEncoded.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/saveInfo")
Call<String> sendInfo(
    @Query("name") String name,
    @Query("family") String family,
    @Query("age") String age
```

And add "/" to base link not here. Also where is the .php end?

Comment: check my comment again.

Comment: What mean ".php" end ??

Comment: Do not you have script file?

Comment: I commented (disable) line "//\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class," in "kernel.php" file and caught  "JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $" error

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 confusion in your question.

```
@POST("/saveInfo")
Call<String> sendInfo(
    @Query("name") String name,
    @Query("family") String family,
    @Query("age") String age
```

Is this POST API or GET API, because you are using @Query annotation which is related to GET API but you are declaring this API as @POST. This can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: I used "@FormUrlEncoded" and "@Field" but I get same error

Comment: Have you tried to hit this API using postman? Is it working fine there ?

Comment: I commented (disable) line "//\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class," in "kernel.php" file and caught  "JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $" error

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your laravel function saveInfo(). It is not returning a json response. in this format

**JSON response**

```
{
   "name":"value",
   "family":"value",
   "age":"value"
}
```

To resolve this modify your code from that

```
public function saveInfo(Request $request)
{
    $student = new Student();
    $student->name = $request->name;
    $student->family = $request->family;
    $student->age= $request->age;
    if($student->save())
       echo "success";
    else
       echo "failed!";
}
```

to this

```
public function saveInfo(Request $request)
{
    $student = new Student();
    $student->name = $request->name;
    $student->family = $request->family;
    $student->age= $request->age;
    $message = "";
    if($student->save()) 
    {
        $message ="success";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $message = "failed!";
    }
    return response()->json(["message" => $message],200);
}
```

You can visit this link for more infomation about Laravel Json response here
[Laravel API Errors and Exceptions: How to Return Responses](https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-api-errors-and-exceptions-how-to-return-responses/)

Laravel HTTP response doc's [HTTP Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses)

Android retrofit POST AND GET with json [Retrofit Android Example with Get and Post Api Request.](https://www.al-burraq.com/blogs/retrofit-android-get-and-post-api-request-tutorial/)